# AngularJS: Sending Authentication Headers over Websocket

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, websocket

I am having difficulty authenticating requests to a WebSocket API.

The Site I am working with (www.bitmex.com) provides a REST API and a WebSocket API.

Both of their API's allow authentication with an API Key.

**Authentication Requirements**

The API provides the following documentation for authentication with API Keys:

```
    Authentication is done by sending the following HTTP headers:

        api-expires: a UNIX timestamp in the future (eg: 5 seconds).
        api-key: Your public API key. This the id param returned when you create an API Key via the API.
        api-signature: A signature of the request you are making. It is calculated as hex(HMAC_SHA256(verb + url + nonce + data)).
```

**REST API**

I've created a NodeJS module for sending requests to the REST API, I've defined the following headers

```
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "BitMEX NodeJS API Client",
        "api-expires": expires,
        "api-key": this.api_key,
        "api-signature": this.signMessage(verb, reqUrl, expires, params)
    };

    where the signMessage function looks like: 

    BitMEX.prototype.signMessage = function signMessage(verb, url, nonce, data) {
        if (!data || _.isEmpty(data)) data = '';
        else if(_.isObject(data)) data = formatParameters(data);

        return crypto.createHmac('sha256', this.secret).update(verb + url + nonce + data).digest('hex');
    };
```

***This works great for the REST API and does everything I need it to in the backend of my application.***

**WebSocket API**

I am trying to use WebSocket get realtime data and display it in a browser based interface.

The documentation on the site states:

```
To use an API Key with websockets, you must sign the initial upgrade request in the same manner you would sign other REST calls.
```

I've been implementing this in AngularJS using the ng-websocket module.

```
    exchange.dataStream = $websocket('wss://testnet.bitmex.com/realtime');

    exchange.dataStream.onMessage(function incoming (message) {
        console.log("BitMEX: WS MESSAGE RECEIVED: " + message.data);    

        // .. handle data here ... 

    });

    exchange.dataStream.send({"op":"getAccount"});
```

**The problem that I've run into is I can't find anyway to send the headers using ng-websocket that are needed for authentication.**

If I am presently logged in to BitMEX from another tab in my browser, this will connect, get the data, and work as expected.

However, if I am not currently logged in to the site, it will throw the following error:

```
    BitMEX: WS MESSAGE RECEIVED: {"status":401,"error":"Not authenticated.","meta":{},"request":{"op":"getAccount"}}
```

There is a python example provided here: https://github.com/BitMEX/market-maker/blob/master/test/websocket-apikey-auth-test.py that goes through the Authentication process, 
but I haven't found a way to accomplish this in AngularJS.

**Summary**

**#1) When logged in to BitMEX, and the Websocket is working, is Chrome somehow using the website's cookies to authenticate the websocket requests?**

Looking at an overview of websockets here: http://enterprisewebbook.com/ch8_websockets.html
The initial handshake upgrades the connection from "HTTP" to the WebSocket protocol,

**#2) Because this initial connection is over HTTP, is there any way to attach the headers required to this initial HTTP request?**

Comment: If you read the Python example, the first thing it sends is `{"op": "authKey", "args": [API_KEY, nonce, signature]}` then it sends `{"op": "getAccount"}`

Comment: Python example [line #44](https://github.com/BitMEX/market-maker/blob/master/test/websocket-apikey-auth-test.py#L44) and [line #51](https://github.com/BitMEX/market-maker/blob/master/test/websocket-apikey-auth-test.py#L51)

Comment: Thanks. This helps, I can use it to authenticate the request now :).

I am still curious to figure out how the WebSocket request is authenticated when I am logged in on another tab in chrome without creating a signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the Python example, the first thing it sends is `{"op": "authKey", "args": [API_KEY, nonce, signature]}` then it sends `{"op": "getAccount"}`

Python example [line #44](https://github.com/BitMEX/market-maker/blob/master/test/websocket-apikey-auth-test.py#L44) and [line #51](https://github.com/BitMEX/market-maker/blob/master/test/websocket-apikey-auth-test.py#L51)

How Chrome does it is another question.

Comment: Turn cookies off and see if a new tab is still logged in. Also open an incognito window and notice that you are no longer logged in.